# Morph between 100 portraits

Tags: after-effects

I`m looking for a workflow to morph between 100 portrait photos without animating every single transition in After Effects.

Are there any tools to achieve this automaticly ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a "new" "Morph Cut" as Premiere Video Transition. You could just place all images in a new Sequence and then copy paste the Video Transition. Remember to adjust the length of the transition itself before copy´n paste and also the length of the images.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a plugin that does this 100% automated for you.  However I have used the steps in this tutorial many times and it works great.

http://cgi.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-facial-morph-without-using-3rd-party-plug-ins--ae-22370

Answer (score 0):

This technique using Time Remap is effective and doesn't require any extra plugins, (but isn't automated):